# I need to align 3 text views which should placed in center of the layout with out using any padding

Tags: android-layout

```
                       TextView
                       TextView TextView
```

The view should be shown like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout width="match_parent" height="match_parent" orientation="vertical">

 <TextView with="wrap_content" height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center"/>


 <LinearLayout width="match_parent" height="match_parent" orientation="horizontal"    android:gravity="center">

   <TextView with="wrap_content" height="wrap_content"/>

   <TextView with="wrap_content" height="wrap_content"/>

 </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please try this......